# How do you access widget ids from one widget to another in Kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I’m using Kivy Screen Manager and do not understand how to access ids from one widget to another.

Example: Having 2 different Screens with a text input box on screen 1 and a label on screen 2.

How do I get whatever the user inputs on Screen 1 to automatically update the label on Screen 2?

I can get it to work if the text input and label are on the same Screen using the self.root.ids.”id_name_example” but it doesn’t update from one screen to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use kivy properties, when set value to property it will automatically update UI
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html

Another (not very optimal) option here is to refresh you screen when you open it.

```
<YourScreen>:
   name: 'your_screen'
   orientation: 'vertical'
   on_pre_enter:
       root.refresh_your_screen()

   # Root widget
   BoxLayout:
       orientation: 'vertical'
       id: 'your_screen_root'
```

And YourScreen.py will contain refresh_your_screen()

```
    def refresh_my_screen(self):
       # Remove all
       for widget in self.ids.your_screen_root.children:
           widget.clear_widgets()  # remove all child's from Layout
       self.ids.your_screen_root.clear_widgets()  # remove all layouts from root

       # Add actual widgets
```